# Unobtrusive validation problem with DropDownListFor in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

Why is it that client validation is getting triggered saying that my Default Theme field is required even if I didn't specify a [Required] attribute in my model?

[image]

Model :

```
public class Site
{
    public int SiteId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    [LocalizedDisplayName("Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    [LocalizedDisplayName("RootDirectory")]
    public string RootDirectory { get; set; }

    [LocalizedDisplayName("DefaultTheme")]
    public int DefaultThemeId { get; set; } // <-- No required attribute here

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    [LocalizedDisplayName("ThemesDirectory")]
    public string ThemesDirectory { get; set; }

    public virtual Theme DefaultTheme { get; set; } // <-- No required attribute here
}
```

View :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.DefaultThemeId,
new SelectList(ViewBag.Themes, "ThemeId", "Name"), string.Empty)
```

I am using Entity Framework 4 with ADO.NET Entity Data Model and mapping the entities to POCOs in my model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because ints have an implicit value. If you want it to have no value, change the type to a nullable int using int?

Comment: If you really want to leave it as int you can set DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes to false in your Global.asax I'd recommend using the int? however.